# 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command, when running npm run build

Tags: node.js, server, node-modules

When cmd tries to run `node_modules/.bin/tsc` I get this error:

```
'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Package.json file contains the following:

```
{
"name": "AFK_Game",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": false,
"bin": {
    "$": "./dist/bin/app.js"
},
"main": "./dist/app",
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build  && cd dist &&  node app",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/tsc"
},

"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.19",
    "@types/node": "8.10.54",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "crc": "^3.8.0",
    "pinus": "1.4.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.5",
    "@types/crc": "^3.4.0",
    "tslint": "5.20.1",
    "typescript": "3.7.3"
}
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I resolved it by making all the characters lowercase and using hyphen (-) instead of adding spaces to separate words in the name of the folder containing project files. The same applies to the parent folders. If any of the parent folders have spaces, special symbols, or uppercase letters (which might cause errors), then use lowercase letters and hyphens (-) instead.

For example:

Replace Folder Name: React App & Website

With Folder Name: react-app-and-website

I hope this may prove to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you switched to the latest npm version ^9.x.

Solution: The script does not require the path to tsc. Just replace `node_modules/.bin/tsc` with `tsc`.

When you perform a `npm run <script>`, `npm run` adds `node_modules/.bin` to the PATH provided to scripts

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-run-script?v=true